# Why this Rvest is not returning any value?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying scrape a webpage with following code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'http://iia.ptpl.co.in/memberdetail.aspx?memid=07833'
webpage <- read_html(url)
unit_data_html <- html_node(webpage,'#owner')
html_text(unit_data_html)
```

I expected the output to be "GURPREET SINGH BASKHI"

but, I am getting just an empty span ("")

```
[1] ""
```

Can someone tell me why? what is wrong with the code?

Comment: But the “owner” `span` in the source code *is* empty: the web app is filled dynamically using JavaScript. To read dynamic web pages, use {RSelenium} instead of {rvest}.

Comment: oh! okay... I will try that... Thank you :)